# Windows IDE for coding python

Tags: windows, python, ide

PyCharm seems to be fine but I think it's not that good since is hard to step into and step over than Visual Studio. However Visual Studio seems to lack what PyCharm is able to do which is create a JSON file.  To debug, step into and over in PyCharm is not just pressing a button like it is in Visual Studio. It's to first put a breakpoint, click run, select the py program you want to run and click shift and the py program.  Programs stops at breakpoint, then press F8 to step over.

Is there a better IDE for Python that can do it easier with all the function of PyCharm and that can use and create forms with the QT module ?

Comment: I can't see how VS can step over/into without first settigng a breakpoint

Comment: Unless it has a "stop on first line" option. But, what's the difficulty in setting a breakpoint, when the IDE is so superior to everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had very good luck with [PyScripter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/). Wikipedia has a list of its [supported features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyScripter).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for something like visual studio then why not use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? It's a free source code editor form microsoft, and by installing the extensions python and a couple of others you can easily debug python files like you want.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ok but I think visual studio are harder to create python json and web files unless you know how to do that ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. JSON files are very standard and can easily be created in any editor. web files? html? css? if you mean that, yes that is the same as elsewhere.

Comment: Ok but I don't know or have created them in visual studio. Seems like I have to create json file in pycharm and then python in visual studio.  I like visual studio as it can easily step into the code line by line than it does in pycharm which makes it easier to code the language.

Comment: Can you pelase explain that "visual studio as it can easily step into the code line by line than it does in pycharm"? I just don't undertsand what you mean

Comment: Ok, in visual studio you can just click F10 to step over and F11 to step into and does not need to put the break point to debug. In pycharm you need to put a break point first then click on the debug program and press F7 to step into and F8 to step over. I was just new to pycharm but I think I am just getting the hang of it that there are pros and cons with each IDE.